Sent each SAP command to another sub and execute it for error handling
When a command is sent to SAP GUI like SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane(170, 25, False) and an error occurs I'd like to log the error and let the script continue after user input (if needed) to fix the error. Next, I want to use the Log to examine the errors and fix them.
I was thinking to do this via an additional sub that handles the SAP GUI command and catches the error like below.
I know that the below code does not workout at all but it's just for illustration of what I'd like to accomplish.
Thanks!

  Private sub DoSomethingInSAP() 
      SAPCommand(SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane(170, 25, False))
      SAPCommand(SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nsu3")
      SAPCommand(SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0))
  End Sub

  Private sub SAPCommand(input as ?????)         '//SAPCommand to be executed
      try
           Run SAPCommand
      Catch ex as Exception
           Log("Error: " & input & vbCRLF & ex.tostring)
           msgbox("First fix the error for command: " & vbCRLF & input & vbCRLF & "Next: Click 'Ok' to continue")
      end try
  end sub


Are you really using VBA?

I would suggest something like the following:
Private Sub DoSomethingInSAP()
   On Error GoTo error

   SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane(170, 25, False)
   SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nsu3"
   SAPsession.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey (0)
   
   Exit Sub
   
error:
   Log("Error: " & input & vbCRLF & ex.tostring)
   MsgBox("First fix the error for command: " & vbCRLF & input & vbCRLF & "Next: Click 'Ok' to continue")
   
   Resume Next
End Sub

If an error occurs with the first FindById, control jumps to the error block where you can do logging and user input.  The Resume Next is the key piece for your scenario.  It will return control to the statement following the statement that threw the error, in this case the second FindById.
One negative with this approach is you won't know which command threw the error for your logging and user input.

Here's one way to do it, but you'll need to add line numbers to each line of code which might raise an error.
You'll also need to "trust access to VB project" in your Excel(?) options.
Hat-tip to Find Error Line Number in VBA
Worth noting that if an error occurs on an unnumbered line then Erl will give the number from the most-recent numbered line (or zero if no numbers were used)
Sub Tester()

10  On Error GoTo haveError:
20  Debug.Print "Before error"
30  Debug.Print 1 / 0
40  Debug.Print "After error"

Exit Sub

haveError:
    If MsgBox("Error '" & Err.Description & "' with:" _
               & vbLf & vbLf & GetLine("Module1", "Tester", Erl) & _
               vbLf & vbLf & "Continue?", vbYesNo, "Error") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
    Resume Next
    
End Sub

'return a numbered a line of code from a named module and method
Function GetLine(module, proc, lineNum)
    Const vbext_pk_Proc = 0
    Dim m As Object, lStart As Long, lEnd As Long, l As Long, txt
    
    Set m = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(module).CodeModule
    lStart = m.ProcStartLine(proc, vbext_pk_Proc)
    lEnd = lStart + m.ProcCountLines(proc, vbext_pk_Proc)
    For l = lStart To lEnd
        txt = Trim(m.Lines(l, 1))
        If txt Like lineNum & " *" Then
            GetLine = txt
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next l
    GetLine = "Line number " & line & " not found"
End Function

